# Rails Model multiple column uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, unique

I am making a Viewer model with

```
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :orders
```

that joins the models Users and Orders with a `:has_many :through => :viewers`.

And the Viewer model has the attributes of `user_id` and `order_id`.

How would I set it up so that new viewers are only accepted if both `user_id` and `order_id` are unique in the same row? I remember in MySQL being able to do so with a flag (although I can't for the life of me remember what it was), but I'm not sure how to do it with Rails.

Can I do something like (for Viewer.rb) `validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :order_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.
I *think* the way to do so is as follows:

in the Viewer model migration file (ie: I should have done this earlier)

```
def self.up
  #create_table code
  end

  add_index :viewers, [:user_id, :order_id], :unique => true
end
```